# Simple Question On Independent Events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I'm reading DeGroot and it says:

> A and B are independent if and only if Pr(A|B) = Pr(A) and Pr(B|A) =
>   Pr(B).

My question is:

- Do both equations need to hold for the two events to be independent or does only one need to hold?
- If both equations need to hold, can someone provide an example where only one holds and the other is violated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent (noted $A \perp B$) if $P( A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, that's the definition of independence for two events.

The definition of $P(A \mid B)$ is
$$
P(A \mid B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
$$

Then

\begin{align*}
A \perp B &\iff P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B) \\
&\iff \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A) P(B)}{P(B)} = P(A) \\
&\iff \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A) P(B)}{P(A)} = P(B) \\
&\iff P(A \mid B) = P(A) \\
&\iff P(B \mid A) = P(B) 
\end{align*}

Thus if $P(A \mid B) = P(A)$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent and you will also have $P(B \mid A) = P(B)$.
To answer your first question : if one holds the other one holds too.

This can be found on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Definition).